# Get specific value when there's multiple class with same name in jquery laravel

Tags: jquery

How to get input value when I have multiple tags with same class name? For example, I have multiple product in my cart. And each product have different `id` & `prod_id`. My problem is whenever I try to get the value from the input field, it always return the first data even though I clicked on the latest.

Here is my blade view:

```
<div class="number-input mb-4">
<input id="qty" class="quantity" min="1" name="quantity" value="{{ $cart->quantity }}" type="number" readonly />
<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="{{ $cart->id }}">
<input type="hidden" class="prod_id" name="prod_id" value="{{ $cart->product_id }}">
<button type="button" class="plus"></button>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery code:

```
$(".plus").click(function(e) {
  let id = $(".id").val();
  let product_id = $(".prod_id").val();
  console.log(id);
  console.log(product_id);
  ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `.closest()` you can look for parents with a selector, then you van find the inputs inside that parent:

```
    let container = $(this).closest('.number-input');
    let id = container.find(".id").val();
    let product_id = container.find(".prod_id").val();
```

Kinda hard to explain, but this way you stay within the same item.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me, and about closest() I'll ready about it later

Comment: A quick tip: you should change the name attribute for your inputs: `name="prod_id[]"` so they post as an array. now the values are overwritten for each product.